# Search API on Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a direct API to call to search through conversations with a search term?

If no direct API, is there an API I can use inside a bot that will allow searching by a term?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no functionality for this, nor a firm ETA.

Answer (score 0):

They hide this stuff.

On purpose.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#search-parameter